# How do I match string with the array of strings

Tags: javascript, angular, web

I have an Array of strings as:

```
todo=[

'Get up',
'Brush my teeth',
'Go to work',
'play Games'
];
```

I am trying to match it with this:

Template:

```
<input (input)="checkArrays($event)" />
```

while in my Component.ts the function I am using for it is :

```
checkArrays(e){
let query=e.target.value;
console.log(query);

let todoResult = this.todo.findIndex((item) => { return item.startsWith(query);})
let doneResult = this.done.findIndex((item) => { return item.startsWith(query);})
if(doneResult!=-1){
  console.log('found in Tasks (done)'+doneResult)
}if(todoResult!=-1){
  console.log('found in Tasks (todo)'+todoResult)
}
```

what this does is that when i start typing 'G' it matches the very first item in the array which is 'Get up' and do not match with 'Go to work'. It matches with 'Go to work' when i type 'Go'. The functionality I want is basically it should give me both the 'Get up' and 'Go to work' when I start typing 'G'. some sort of the sub-string like functionality.

Comment: The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the condition, you need to use filter instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the condition, you need to use filter instead.

```js
todo=[
'Get up',
'Brush my teeth',
'Go to work',
'play Games'
];


console.log(todo.filter(item => item.startsWith("G")));

// or 

// Better one is using regex -->
console.log(todo.filter(item => /^g/gi.test(item))); // for case-insensitive search
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed to implement case-insensitive search next. You saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `filter()` instead of `findIndex()`. So it can be:

```js
checkArrays(e) {
  const query = e.target.value;
  
  const todoResult = this.todo.filter(item => item.startsWith(query));
  const doneResult = this.done.filter(item => item.startsWith(query));
  
  if (doneResult.length > 0) {
    console.log(`found in Tasks (done) ${doneResult}`)
  }
  if (todoResult.length > 0) {
    console.log(`found in Tasks (todo) ${todoResult}`)
  }
}
```